# Why games with low system requirements are lagging?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, gaming, minecraft

I got a HP laptop and I dual-boot Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit with Kali Linux 64-bit.I installed Minecraft and Counter Strike to see how they are running and both of them were lagging a lot.I couldn't understand why,because the requirements are met for sure and I installed Windows a week ago...My specifications are:
-processor: AMD quad-core; 1.5 GHz; cache L2 512 kb
-RAM Memory:4 Gb; DDR3; 1600 MHz;
-Hard disk:500 Gb; 5400 rpm; SATA
-Video Card:integrated; AMD Radeon Mobility; HD 8330; DirectX 11 support
Also,three months ago I got ubuntu 14.04 installed and Minecraft was running smoothly (most of the time),I don't understand why it lags so much now,so if anyone knows what's the problem,please tell me.Thanks!

Comment: Minecraft isn't exactly a "game with low system requirements". ;)

Answer (score 0):

HP and Canonicle work together so UBUNTU probably has better, if not proprietary display drivers than KALI.
Your AMD Radeon Mobility; HD 8330 uses shared system memory.
If Minecraft is multi-threaded, it is only in the most recent snaphots.
For your Win 7:
Defrag with a performance defrag program.
Look into shutting down un-needed services (alacrity is a program that will do this).
Use the latest video-drivers.
See if latest Minecraft does use multi-thread so you can use all your cores.